# PHP email send form - drop down list on $_POST send form

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Here is my html and php code:

```
<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset >
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
        <input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />
        <div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
        <div class='container'>
            Years Active (from and to):<br/>
            <select name='years_active_from'>
                <option value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('NULL') ?>'>select</option>
                <option value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('from 2013') ?>'>2013</option>
                <option value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('from 2012') ?>'>2012</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>
            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the different drop down options to change the  `var $years_active_from;`  to each of the different years, 2012, 2013 and post `NULL` if the drop down menu is not used.

`value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('NULL') ?>'` is not changing the `$years_active_from`, what is the correct coding for this?

Comment: How about giving us the rest of the code that's necessary to answer the question?  Where is $formproc?

Comment: If you want to post null if the user has not interacted with the selection but you will have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am not 100% sure I understand what you are looking for, but my guess is that you want to have the first drop down option pre-selected on page load.  For that, you would need to do add the `selected` attribute to the option you want to show as selected:

```
<option selected value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('NULL') ?>'>select</option>
```

Comment: the code is not changing the $years_active_from variable when different drop down menus options are selected

Comment: Are you saying that when you select a different option (like "2013"), the dropdown stays stuck on "select"?

Comment: thank you for the reply steve. the html drop down works ok, it is not changing the php variable when they are selected. $years_active_from is staying empty. is value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('NULL') ?>' the correct coding?

Comment: How is `$years_active_from` to be changing? When you change the dropdown in the client, there is no more PHP, so that variable does not exist.  Are you saying the variable is not correctly showing up after you submit the form back to the server? How are you getting the variable when you submit the form?

Comment: i am trying to get **$years_active_from** to be changed to **from 2013** when 2013 is selected, for example. is this value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('from 2013') ?>' 

is this the correct code to change the **$years_active_from** to **from 2013** ?

Comment: I don't think you understand how PHP/HTML works.  If you select 2013 from the dropdown, there is no more `$years_active_from` PHP variable.

Comment: yes, i am new to php. how do i get the value that is selected from the drop down menu?

Comment: You can get the selected value in the PHP file that this form is being submitted to (whatever `<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>` is) by doing `$y_a_f = $_POST['years_active_from'];`

Comment: thank you for your continued help steve. i am having trouble getting the dropdown to send the value entered to my php email send php, if i use the following code, it will send correctly`<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Years Active (from and to): </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='years_active_from' id='years_active_from' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('years_active_from') ?>' maxlength="100" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>` but if i try adapt the code for a dropdown menu it doesnt work, i am trying to correct the code